# Getting the current Directory

Tags: c#, path, directory, filepath

I have been working with a simple program essentially designed to be digital flash cards. Ideally, I want the program to be portable. I am trying to get the current directory. My setup is this:

I have a FileIO.cs method which reads currentDir/Data. I then have a winform which calls the method and retrieves a string[] array of the list of folders. Both of these methods are public static. I then have a separate button to create controls on the form.

The problem:
I have cleaned/rebuilt the solution and been using the debugger; The program is running from C:\Users\user\a\b\c\solution\bin\debug. The control (radioButton) I created to verify this data is telling me the 'currentDir' is C:\Users\user and not the programs current directory.

Notes:
I have manually created Debug\Data and 4 folders within the data folder so I am 100% sure they exist. No warnings or compile or run time errors are thrown. Card_Base.GetGrades is automatically called on form load successfully.

I have also confirmed the Release folder is empty and not being used. Also I have a backup program which shows an icon when a file is being uploaded to my backup every time the file(s) change. So I am 100% sure bin\debug is the proper working folder in this scenario.

Perhaps what is puzzling me most is that I have a totally separate program written on the same PC using the same IDE and it properly retrieves the path using the same setup.

In FileIO.cs

```
//public static string pathPortable = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        public static string pathPortable = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

static string[] grade1;

    public static string[] GetGrade()
    {
        string fullPath = FileIO.pathPortable + @"\Data";
        grade1 = Directory.GetDirectories(fullPath);

        return grade1;
    }
```

in Card_Base.cs

```
public static List<RadioButton> buttonGrade = new List<RadioButton>(10);
    public static void GetGrades()
    {
        string[] grade2 = FileIO.GetGrade();
        //Proper and accurate names of the folders I manually added
        //C:\Users\user\a\b\c\solution\bin\debug\Data\K
        //C:\Users\user\a\b\c\solution\bin\debug\Data\1
        //C:\Users\user\a\b\c\solution\bin\debug\Data\2
        //C:\Users\user\a\b\c\solution\bin\debug\Data\3


        MessageBox.Show("" + grade2[0]); //Information (entire path) is accurate as of this line

        int x = 5;
        int y = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < grade2.Count(); i++)
        {
            y = i * 21;
            Card_Base.buttonGrade.Add(new RadioButton());
            Card_Base.buttonGrade[i].Text = grade2[i];
            MessageBox.Show("" + buttonGrade[i].Text); //Proper entire path is shown here!
            Card_Base.buttonGrade[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);

        }
    }
```

The control whose .text property which shows C:\Users\User, not the Bin\Debug folder.

```
        private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("abc:" + buttonGrade[0].Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonGrade.Count(); i++)
        {
            panelGrade.Controls.Add(buttonGrade[i]);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("def:" + buttonGrade[0].Text); //Proper string path is displayed in the popup box here!
    }
```

Result: ???
Four vertically lined radioButtons on a form panel which all have text reading "C:\Users\user\"

Update1:
The text also appears slightly misaligned, slightly higher than the radioButton bubble itself, very strange. However, I've gone back into the editor and confirmed the panelGrade is initially empty. Click/Drag grabs nothing and right clicking the panel does not reveal any underlying objects in the panel's space.

After modifying the target directory to its parent (1 level higher), each messageBox checkpoint reveals the proper string/path is being sent in. The visible radioButton when the program is launcher, after the "test" button is pushed is the only occurrence of this unusual text/string appearing anywhere.

Placing messageBoxes before/after the loop within the test button itself shows that the control (radioButton in buttonGrade[0]) DOES contain the proper string / text / path. Thus the change must occur at some point after the buttonTest code is finished executing.

Update2:
I just opened a brand new solution and copy/pasted the relevant code eliminating anything extraneous. Named all the items/controls with the same names. Completely bare bones. Exact same problem.

HOWEVER, when I change radioButtons to TextBoxs ... the program displays the proper information. Um. What???

Update 3:
Looking through the MSDN radioButtons are derived from buttonBase. The only relevant event I see at a glance is the textChanged event. While it does note that the way the text property of derived classes like radioButton varies, it fails to specify exactly how or what limits it has. Control.Text is simply a System.String , thus I see no reason why a radioButton would not be able to contain that information.

I tried creating a 'test2' button to change 'buttonGrade[0].Text = FileIO.pathPortable;' . Oddly enough, it does not change the text all. Nor does it throw an error.

AH HA! I noticed that the folder after user was my google drive, which is "Google Drive" and has a space in it. I then copied my trash program to C:\and named it TrashMe2 and ensured no folder names contained spaces. The result was "C:\TrashMe2\bi". I then tried "1234567890123456789". The result was that it showed up to the second 3.

The radioButton wasn't receiving a different string and the string/path/data was never changed. It simply showed a 'different folder' because that, by luck of the draw' was the exact number of visible characters it showed. Because I created the radioButtons programmatically, AutoSize did NOT default to true. The proper string was part of the radioButton, it simply was not all visible.

And for security reasons (and a bit of humor), I actually call my user account "user". So it wasn't a scenario where I would see C:\Users\JoeNomidBlow was cut off.

I feel... rather stupid at this particular moment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you check if the radio button text is not occupied by some other control? Right-click in browser and inspect element to see what text actually rendered to the radio button.

Comment: Just to be sure, what happens when you replace `FileIO.pathPortable + @"\Data";` with `FileIO.pathPortable`; ?

Comment: @Rob - I made the adjustment and the program still has the same end result. The messageBoxes along the way show the information in the new (higher up) folder properly. There is only a "Data" folder inside of the Debug folder that is being searched (where the actively debugged app is being run from).

Comment: @Siva Gopal - I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the 'text occupied by some other control'. The text property only accepts a string, not an object. As for the panel itself, it is initially empty before I programmatically add these radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically adding a control, particularly a radioButton, does not automatically set the autoSize property to true. When creating a radioButton programatically, one must be sure to add

```
radioButton.Autosize = true;
```

or as this case is/was

```
buttonGrade[i].Autosize = true;
```

Otherwise the visible space of the text is shortened. In this case, leaving behind a partial path. Which coincidentally happens to be identical to a different valid path.